# how to call a specific controller which is common for 2 prefix routes in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my program i called a controller function using redirect action method which is commonly applied for 2 prefix routes(admin,manager) when i am on admin route i tried to call the controller function which triggers the manager route controller function 
here is the controller call

```
 return redirect()->action('UserController@index');
```

prefix routes definied

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'manager'), function(){
Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');
});
```

when i am on admin prefix *localhost/admin/user* route. i triggered controller call ***return redirect()->action('UserController@index');*** which triggers the manager prefix controller. the route will changed to localhost/manager/user why this is happening please help me on this and i am using LARAVEL 5.2

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the  [Named Routed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes)  to avoid the conficts.

In your route give name to every route.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
Route::get('/user', array('as' => 'admin.user', 'uses' => 'UserController@index');
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'manager'), function(){
Route::get('/user', array('as' => 'manager.user', 'uses' => 'UserController@index');
});
```

Now in your `route` you can routed by it's name,

```
return redirect()->route('admin.user');
```

**or**

```
return redirect()->route('manager.user');
```

It might help you.